# Javascript ArrayBuffer equivalent in Swift or iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, arraybuffer

I want to know what is the Javascript ArrayBuffer equivalent in Swift or ios.

Basically I have a Swift struct that I want to store as a blob (data stored based on memory layout) and pass this blob to Javascript ArrayBuffer where I can , based on defined set layout extract data from ArrayBuffer

I havent yet managed to save the struct from Swift as a binary/memory blob. Struggling to understand the memory layout configuration. I thought it would be similar to structs in C but they are not.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in Javascript, so I may be talking nonsense.
It seems like you can achieve what you want if your struct `S` implements the `Codable` protocol. Then you can transform it to a `Data` blob using an encoder, like this:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
do {
 let data = try encoder.encode(s)
 // do what you want with the blob
} catch {
 // handle error
}
```

And back to `S`, like this:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
 let s = try decoder.decode(S.self, from: data)
} catch {
 // handle error
}
```

If `S` is `Codable`, `[S]` (an `Array<S>`) will also be `Codable`.

You can probably pass the data to your scriptas a String, then you'll have to transform your data do string with `JSONSerialization`